How can I center vertically a tikz picture in a tabular?
I would like the tikz figure to be centred in the cell of my table and for this to work for each cell. I try a lot of option like \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3} but it doesn't work well! In particular, the box for the first equation is stuck at the top!
This is my MWE:
\documentclass[french,a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[
            c/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=2cm,minimum height =0.8cm, inner sep=1mm, align=center},
            f/.style={draw, thick,minimum width=1cm,minimum height =1cm,inner sep =1 mm,-latex},
        ]
        % Les cadres de texte
        \node[c] (a) {$x+2>8$};
        \node[c] (b) [yshift=-2cm] {$x>6$};
        % flèches 
        \draw[f] (a.west) to[bend right=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$-2$}  (b.west);

        \draw[f] (a.east) to[bend left=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$-2$}  (b.east);
    \end{tikzpicture} &    \\
    \hline&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


The TeX primitive for putting an object vertically centered is \vcenter. It creates a box like \vbox and measures its height plus depth. Then it puts this box vertically centered to the horizontal math axis. The math axis is a horizontal line relative to which the math objects like +, -, (, ) are placed. The math axis is somewhat higher placed than baseline. The distance between math axis and baseline is defined in used math font. That is the reason why \vcenter works only in math mode. So, you have to write $\vcenter{image}$. Moreover, the TikZ picture in LaTeX leaves horizontal mode (this is a LaTeX's not so good feature), so you must to protect the leaving of vertical mode by extra \hbox and you have to write $\vcenter{\hbox{image}}$.
Your example can look like this:
\documentclass[french,a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
$\vcenter{\hbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            c/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=2cm,minimum height =0.8cm, inner sep=1mm, align=center},
            f/.style={draw, thick,minimum width=1cm,minimum height =1cm,inner sep =1 mm,-latex},
        ]
        % Les cadres de texte
        \node[c] (a) {$x+2>8$};
        \node[c] (b) [yshift=-2cm] {$x>6$};
        % flèches 
        \draw[f] (a.west) to[bend right=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$-2$}  (b.west);

        \draw[f] (a.east) to[bend left=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$-2$}  (b.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}}$ & next text   \\
    \hline&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


You can use baseline=(current bounding box.center) to achieve this:
\documentclass[french,a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[
            c/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=2cm,minimum height =0.8cm, inner sep=1mm, align=center},
            f/.style={draw, thick,minimum width=1cm,minimum height =1cm,inner sep =1 mm,-latex},
            baseline=(current bounding box.center)
        ]
        % Les cadres de texte
        \node[c] (a) {$x+2>8$};
        \node[c] (b) [yshift=-2cm] {$x>6$};
        % flèches 
        \draw[f] (a.west) to[bend right=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$-2$}  (b.west);

        \draw[f] (a.east) to[bend left=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$-2$}  (b.east);
    \end{tikzpicture} &  something else  \\
    \hline&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


If you don't want to put the absolute center of the tikzpicture on the baseline but instead the baseline of a node in that picture (like the -2 node in the east) you can use something like the following:
\documentclass[french,a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[
            c/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=2cm,minimum height =0.8cm, inner sep=1mm, align=center},
            f/.style={draw, thick,minimum width=1cm,minimum height =1cm,inner sep =1 mm,-latex},
            baseline=(c.base)
        ]
        % Les cadres de texte
        \node[c] (a) {$x+2>8$};
        \node[c] (b) [yshift=-2cm] {$x>6$};
        % flèches 
        \draw[f] (a.west) to[bend right=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$-2$}  (b.west);

        \draw[f] (a.east) to[bend left=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white](c){$-2$}  (b.east);
    \end{tikzpicture} &  something else  \\
    \hline&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}



Another approach with the adjustbox package:
\documentclass[french,a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=c}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            c/.style={draw, thick, minimum width=2cm,minimum height =0.8cm, inner sep=1mm, align=center},
            f/.style={draw, thick,minimum width=1cm,minimum height =1cm,inner sep =1 mm,-latex},
        ]
        % Les cadres de texte
        \node[c] (a) {$x+2>8$};
        \node[c] (b) [yshift=-2cm] {$x>6$};
        % flèches 
        \draw[f] (a.west) to[bend right=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$-2$}  (b.west);

        \draw[f] (a.east) to[bend left=45] node[midway, draw, ellipse, fill=white]{$-2$}  (b.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
 &  c  \\
    \hline&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


